# convert Datetime to simple Date

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce, datetime-format, date-conversion

I am having trouble converting a variable that's in String format (from a DateTime selector control on a form) to simple Date.

I am trying the conversion because I am getting the below error message:

> INVALID_FIELD: \nAND c.Status__c = 'Closed' AND c.Close_Date__c >
>   2013-07-01T00:00:00Z\n   ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:326\nvalue of filter
>   criterion for field 'Close_Date__c' must be of type date and should
>   not be enclosed in quotes

I tried:

```
sQry += " AND c.Close_Date__c > " + DateTime.ParseExact(filterFromDate, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " AND c.Close_Date__c < " + DateTime.ParseExact(filterFromDate, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it's not accepting it (compiler doesn't recognise `CultureInfo`.

where am I going wrong please?

MORE INFO:
Sorry I should mention we're using this query against a SalesForce object referencing an instance of SalesForce

Comment: Have you tried using `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` on your DateTimes?

Comment: Are you trying to use it in an SQL statement? If so, you should probably take a look at [Parameterized Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

Comment: @Corak: Well, we're querying a SalesForce object so it's not actually a SQL Server... I tried the answer below but now get an error that the variable **filterFromDate** is not recognized as a valid date even though its value is "2013-07-01T00:00:00Z"

Comment: For the database, `date` and `datetime` are two different things. If you're working with some kind of implementation of [IDataParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Data.IDataParameter.aspx) you might need to specify the [DbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.idataparameter.dbtype.aspx) to be [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx).

Comment: for a date, its expecting 2013-07-01 no time part.

Answer (score 1):

add System.Globalization and then...

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(filterFromDate, "dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: thanks but when I added that code (`var onewFilterDate = DateTime.ParseExact(filterFromDate, "dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);)` I get this error **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: my variable that I want to convert to proepr date has a string value of "2013-07-01T00:00:00Z" and I am getting an error as in my above commecnt

Comment: why T and Z is required in your "2013-07-01T00:00:00Z"? what if you dont write it then?

Comment: when I try the query with filterFromDate set to "01 Jul 2013" I still get the error `nvalue of filter criterion for field 'Close_Date__c' must be of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes`

Answer (score 1):

Updated...

And what about this (I made a lot of assumptions.....)
Where

```
string filterFromDate = "2013-07-01T00:00:00Z";

sQry += " AND c.Close_Date__c > " + DateTime.Parse(filterFromDate).Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzzzz") + " AND c.Close_Date__c < " + DateTime.Parse(filterFromDate).Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzzzz");
```

<strike>Or better with SqlParameters</strike>

```
string filterFromDateStr = "2013-07-01T00:00:00Z";

//Just the date since we don't want to use the Time
var filterFromDate = DateTime.Parse(filterFromDateStr ).Date;

sQry += " AND c.Close_Date__c > @filterFromDate AND c.Close_Date__c < @filterFromDate";

IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = connection.ConnectionTimeout;
cmd.CommandText = sQuery;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@filterFromDate ",filterFromDate ));

md.Connection = connection;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: thanks but it's not a SQL Server, it's a SalesForce instance that we're querying

Comment: I knew I made a lot of assumptions, and what exception does it throws with this `sQry += " AND c.Close_Date__c > " + DateTime.Parse(filterFromDate).Date + " AND c.Close_Date__c < " + DateTime.Parse(filterFromDate).Date;` for curiosity.

Comment: it gives a SalesForce error as in the question, so I have been struggling with my basic c# and .NET knowledge to send a Date format rather than a string.

Comment: Ok, one last try for me...  `sQry += " AND c.Close_Date__c > " + DateTime.Parse(filterFromDate).Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzzzz") + " AND c.Close_Date__c < " + DateTime.Parse(filterFromDate).Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzzzz");` hope it works....